# Drools 5.6 version with JDK 8

Tags: java, java-8, drools

I am trying to upgrade my existing application running on JDK 7 to 8. My current version of drools is 5.6.0 Final version which does not work with JDK8 due to JDT Core Batch Compiler version 3.5.1 compatibility issues. The stack trace throws "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException” – which clearly indicates that the exception is thrown by a class file reader when encountering an error in decoding information contained in a .class file

We upgraded the ecj library to 4.6.1 and we dont see the issue anymore but we see a different error during runtime.

Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Duplicate team entries for overlapping time period are not allowed - Team']
com/company/abc/athena/services/validation/Rule_Duplicate_team_entries_for_overlapping_time_period_are_not_allowed_$u45$_Team1529838393.java (2:102) : Only a type can be imported. com.company.abc.athena.services.validation.TeamValidationMessage resolves to a package

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. The upgraded ecj library was conflicting with the tomcat's ecj 4.3.1 library. I removed the maven dependency for ecj from my app and used the Tomcat's ecj library and that resolved the issue.